# How to move GridView to beginning ?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have a GridView and one button, and I need that when the user presh the button move the gridView at the beginning.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try : mGridView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);